# Compare values between rows for specific columns

Tags: r

I have a rather curious question, but I hope I can find an answer. Unfortunately, the search function in stackoverflow didn't help me with this one.
I have the following dataset structure:

```
my.df <- data.frame(prs_id = c(1234, 1255, 1556, 3173),
                    vrs_id = c(3145, 3145, 3333, 3333),
                    V1_2017 = c(12,14,12,35),
                    V2_2017 = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                    V1_2018 = c(13,16,13,34),
                    V2_2018 = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                    V1_2019 = c(15,17,17,45),
                    V2_2019 = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                    V1_2020 = c(17,17,22,45),
                    V2_2020 = c("A", "B", "C", "D"))
```

As you might see, I filtered duplicates from a larger dataset (duplicates in "vrs_id"). The duplicates are not supposed to be there and the dataset is at the moment in wide format. I need a way to decide, which "vrs_id" to keep and which to drop. Therefore the function must compare each corresponding values of V1_2020 to V1_2017, according to the "vrs_id" they belong to. V2 is just to visualize, that there are more (actually 13) variables between the V1 variables.
E.g. "vrs_id" == 3145 requires to check, which V1_2020 (45 and 22) is larger. If non is larger (see 17 vs 17 for vrs_id == 3145), the function should move to the next variable V1_2019 and do the same. If, at the end, there is no difference in the duplicates, the first (according to the rownumber in the dataframe) should be chosen.

The subset only has duplicates and the corresponding original inside, so a potential function must not be capable of comparing even more values across rows. I tried to include pmax, but when grouping the dataframe by var_id, it automatically chose var_id as maximum in the line. But excluding var_id from the subset, consequently, gave an error in grouping because the grouping variable was missing.

Is there anybody with an idea to compute this comparisons?
Any help would be appreciated!

Edit:
The expected output should look like this:

```
new.df <- data.frame(
          prs_id = c(1255, 3173),
          vrs_id = c(3145, 3333),
          V1_2017 = c(14,35),
          V2_2017 = c("B", "D"),
          V1_2018 = c(16,34),
          V2_2018 = c("B", "D"),
          V1_2019 = c(17,45),
          V2_2019 = c("B", "D"),
          V1_2020 = c(17,45),
          V2_2020 = c("B", "D"))
```

prs_id No. 2 and 4 should be kept, since for prs_id No. 2 in V1_2019 17>15 (despite in V1_2020 17=17) and for No. 4 V1_2020 shows 45 > 22, therefore prs_id No. 3 is discarded.

Comment: Could you please include a data frame showing the expected output from this sample?

Comment: Done that for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be an option, using tidyverse packages.

Note this only works where all values for one `prs_id` are greater than or equal to the variables in duplicate `prs_id`s.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)


df1 <- 
  my.df %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("V1")) %>% 
  group_by(vrs_id, name) %>%
  mutate(max_val = if_else(value == max(value), 0, 1)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(prs_id) %>% 
  mutate(prs_discard = sum(max_val)) %>% 
  filter(prs_discard == 0) %>% 
  select(-c(max_val, prs_discard)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)

df1
#> # A tibble: 2 x 10
#> # Groups:   prs_id [2]
#>   prs_id vrs_id V2_2017 V2_2018 V2_2019 V2_2020 V1_2017 V1_2018 V1_2019 V1_2020
#>    <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1   1255   3145 B       B       B       B            14      16      17      17
#> 2   3173   3333 D       D       D       D            35      34      45      45
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>